# Как разместить Google Map с маршрутом от геолокации пользователя до маркера?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api

Имеется сайт и задание от заказчика выводить построение маршрута на карте от геолокации пользователя до точки на карте. Изучил Google Map API, "из коробки" они такого решения не предлагают, как я понимаю, нужно получить широту и долготу в корректном виде, а потом поставить ее в значение `origin` функции `calculateAndDisplayRoute`. Короче, ничего не выходит, выводится неверное значение.

```
var visaby = {lat: 53.919844, lng: 27.582813};
    var myLatLng;

    function initMap() {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: visaby
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: visaby,
            map: map
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    }

    function geoSuccess(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    myLatLng = {
        lat: latitude,
        lng: longitude
    };
  }  
    
    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
            origin: myLatLng, 
            destination: visaby,  
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте применить следующий код для ваших карт:

```js
<script>if (navigator.geolocation) { //Проверяет, поддерживает ли браузер геолокацию
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {  //Это получает
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                    //текущую геолокацию
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                 //пользователя
     var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); //Создает переменную для координат карты
     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
     var mapOptions = //Sets map options
     {
       zoom: 15,  //Устанавливает уровень масштабирования (0-21)
       center: coords, //зум для местоположения пользователя
       mapTypeControl: true, //позволяет выбрать тип карты, например карта или спутник
       navigationControlOptions:
       {
         style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL //размер элементов управления сетью, например зум
       },
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //устанавливает тип карты с опциями:ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, TERRIAN
     };
     map = new google.maps.Map( /*creates Map variable*/ document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions /*Создает новую карту, используя переданные необязательные параметры в параметре mapOptions.*/);
     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
     var request = {
       origin: coords,
       destination: '65.791238, 21.657444',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
     }); 
     
   });
    
 }
 </script>
```

Это работает во всех браузерах, кроме Сафари. Раньше работало и в Сафари, но не теперь. Причина этого мне неизвестна.

Comment: Зачем добавить код в сниппет если он не рабочий?

Comment: @Raz Galstyan Пример карты с этим кодом https://sweden-tourist.com/sights/en/maps/borgholm.html . Карты могут не работать, если ваше текущее местоположение слишком далеко от выбранного объекта.

Comment: Вот это уже норм. И скажу я далеко но все ровно маршрут нормально показывает. +1 вам.

Comment: @Raz Galstyan Отлично.