# открыть google map на текущем положении пользователя

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

День добрый. При запуске карты мое приложение открывает карту мира. Если нажать на кнопку геолокации, то камера улетает на мое текущее положение. Как сделать, чтобы карта сразу открывалась на моем местоположении? Я примерно представляю, что нужно получить мои координаты и использовать `mGoogleMap.moveCamera(мои координаты);` но как получить мои координаты? Весь день ищу информацию, не могу найти. пробовал так:

```
private void getMyPosition() {
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mGoogleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), mGoogleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16);
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

но IDE говорит, что метод `getMyLocation()`устарел, а в процессе запуска на телефоне выдает ошибку

> getLatitude() on a null object reference

подскажите плиз как нужно сделать?

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/5330439)

Comment: [или тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Comment: Тут тоже интересно: Нетрадиционный контент: PR-трюки для SEO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772907/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-google-map-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/773210#773210